# Find the value of "a" given the general solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCgO7.png)

$$\color{blue}{[UPDATE]}$$ The differential equation shown in the image isn't the correct differential equation. I consulted the source of the problem and I found that the correct differential equation should be:

The general solution to the differential equation
$$(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{4x^3y}{(1\color{red} + x^2)} = 1$$
where $-1 < X < 1$, can be written in the form $$y = \frac{\color{red} {x(a+x^2)}+K}{a(1 - x^4)}$$ **Find the value of "a"**

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math Stack exchange! Typically, your question will be better received if you use $\mathjax$! Simply put dollar signs $\$$your equation$\$$ and play with it until you like the output.

Comment: While you're at it, show us your attempt. We can't guess how you used the integrating factor if you can't see it.

Comment: Hi Snared, thank you for your comment, I already edited my question so you can see it better, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Since you are given the general form of $y$, just differentiate it and choose $a$ and $K$ to make it match $4x^3y/(1-x^2)^2 +1/(1-x^2)$.

Comment: Hello Sean Roberson, thank you for your comment, I already added my attempt, sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: Hi marty cohen, thanks for your suggestion, I believe you mean that I should differentiate the solution given in the problem statement, am I right?

Comment: @Gonçalo I consulted the source and the problem and it shows a different differential equation than the one that the image shows. I added more details about this error above in the problem post.